# Не запускается ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lubuntu

Не стартует нормально сервер, чистил комп от пыли, теперь выводит это

[image]

а дальше ничего не происходит. Работаю только в терминале, если при старте таб нажимать и выбрать убунту то все нормально стартует, раньше сразу стартовал нормально

[image]

[image]

Comment: Возможно это появилось после каких-то обновлений похоже связанных с ядром, как я могу откатиться?

Comment: Ну бубен обычно не грохает старые ядра. Попробуй много раз жать `Esc`, чтобы попасть в `grub` и там прогрузить старое ядро.

Comment: А ещё я бы отрубил все винты кроме загрузочного. Ну так, на всякий случай чисто для диагностики.